# Sparse SVD on C#

Tags: c#, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am writing a C# application working with SVD on very large matrices. Eventually SVD computation fails because of "not enough" memory. I was thinking to use sparse matrices, but then the SVD will not work.

Is there a fast SVD sparse implementation for C#, or what recommendations do you have?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used DllImport and SVDLIBC ;)

Comment: How big are the matrices?  This question has some suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552535/svd-algorithm-implementation